# How to get detail error info from E_FAIL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, mfc, atl

When I use ATL in MFC Application(Don't ask me why, just because I like), sometimes I got the error code: **E_FAIL**. However, it's almost useless for me to locate the specific reason.

I have googled so many times, but found nothing related. I thought there should be something like `try{} catch{}` in ATL.

Here's some sample code:

```
CAxWindow  m_wndView;  // ActiveX host window class.
CComPtr<IWMPPlayer>  m_spWMPPlayer;  // Smart pointer to IWMPPlayer interface.

AtlAxWinInit();
CComPtr<IAxWinHostWindow>  spHost;
HRESULT  hr;
CRect rcClient;
GetClientRect(&rcClient);
m_wndView.Create(m_hWnd, rcClient, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
//when I switch to Static Link to ATL from Dynamic Link to ATL, I always get E_FAIL
hr = m_wndView.QueryHost(&spHost);
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I have updated the post, please check and give your recommendations.

Comment: Well, I don't know for sure, but `CWindow::Create` references `CreateWindow` in the remarks section, and `CreateWindow` provides additional error information through `GetLastError`. I don't know if that means that `CWindow::Create` does, too, though. I can't find any that takes the arguments you pass, though, just that `CAxWindow` derives from `CWindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is entirely function specific. Think of piece of code [on the other side] that does `return E_FAIL;` What additional detail one can get from it? Chances are high you have no detail at all.

Sometimes you can obtain additional information using [`GetErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API which in your case - having your code snippet in mind - is unlikely.

The best you can do is to step inside to reach as close as possible to the origin of the code in order to tell where it comes from.

Comment: You did solve my problem. I debug the code line by line and found that if defined the macro _ATL_DLL, all worked properly.  Thank you very much for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `_com_error` class.
Construct an object of this class by passing in the `HRESULT` value and then use its `WCode` or `ErrorMessage` methods to get the error code mapped to the `HRESULT` value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
 
I have did as what you said, but I only get the error message:
Unspecified error.
 
Here is my code:

_com_error err(hr);
auto  d = err.WCode();
auto s = err.Description();
auto msg = err.ErrorMessage();//Unspecified error

Comment: That will never get better until you use the _com_error(HRESULT, IErrorInfo, bool) constructor.  QI for ISupportErrorInfo first to check if it is available, then call GetErrorInfo()